# חזרה שבועה לסיני

Tags: purim-torah-in-jest

The gemara states explicitly (Bava Metzia 3a)

> תני רבי חייא מנה לי בידך
> Rabbi Chiya teaches: "You owe me 100 zuz."

I showed this gemara to my chavrusa and told him that I expected to be paid in full right after shabbos. He insisted that this was only a single witness and therefore he is only obligated to swear. I argued that as a believing Jew, he cannot take an oath deliberately contradicting anything in the Gemara and if he were to take such an oath it would automatically be considered a sh'vuat shav.

Who is right?

---

## This question is [Purim Torah](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Purim_Torah) and is not intended to be taken completely seriously. See the [Purim Torah policy](http://meta.judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/797/).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's a *machlokes amoraim*. As the *g'mara* continues:

> והלה אומר אין לך בידי כלום / Wahala says: "You owe me nothing."

Since גדול מרבן שמו (a rabbi in the Talmud without "Rabbi" before his name is greater than one with), we rule like Wahala.

Your friend owes you nothing.

Comment: I can't believe I accepted this answer even though you paskened against me!